# How to wait for values then return an object

Tags: typescript, async-await, promise, callback, firebase-storage

I am uploading image files to a server, and want to return the download url and upload percentage with my upload method.

Right now this works, but in the future, id like to be able to upload multiple images with this same component, and display a table underneath the upload form, with names of files successfully uploades, and button to delete them.

I was wondering if someone could point me in the right direction with using a promise or async callback to accomplish essentially pushing a new `{ downloadURL : Observable<string>, uploadPercentage : Observable<number> }` object to an array whenever a newly uploaded file is available.

upload method, inside upload-form component.ts

```js
  upload(file) {
    // this.id = Math.random().toString(36).substring(2);
    
    const folder = this.mode == 'single' ? 'titleCardImages' : 'contentImages' 


    const filePath = `${folder}/${file.name}`;
    const fileRef = this.afStorage.ref(filePath);
    const task = this.afStorage.upload(filePath, file)
    // observe percentage changes
    this.uploadPercent = task.percentageChanges();
    // get notified when the download URL is available
    task.snapshotChanges().pipe(
        finalize(() => this.downloadURL = fileRef.getDownloadURL() )
    )
    .subscribe()
    }
```

editNewsComponent.html (excerpt) mat dialog for

```html
<h2 mat-dialog-title>Create, Update or delete news</h2>

<mat-dialog-content [formGroup]="form">

  <mat-form-field>
      <input matInput
              placeholder="Title"
              formControlName="title">
  </mat-form-field> <br>


  <br><label for="titleCardImage">Title Card Image:</label> <br>
  <upload-image
    mode="single"
    label="Enter a title card image">
  </upload-image>


  <!-- <button (click)="fileInput.click()">
    <span>Select</span>
    <input #fileInput type="file" (change)="upload($event)" style="display:none;" />
    
  
  </button> <br> -->


  


  <mat-form-field>
    <textarea matInput
            placeholder="a short description"
            formControlName="description"></textarea>
  </mat-form-field> <br>

  <mat-form-field>
    <textarea matInput
            placeholder="Body/Content of the news piece"
            formControlName="body"></textarea>
  </mat-form-field> <br>


  <label id="example-radio-group-label">Tags: <br></label>
  <mat-chip-list aria-label="tag selection" >
    <mat-chip>One fish</mat-chip>
    <mat-chip>Two fish</mat-chip>
    <mat-chip color="primary" selected>Primary fish</mat-chip>
    <mat-chip color="accent" selected>Accent fish</mat-chip>
  </mat-chip-list>
  
</mat-dialog-content>

<mat-dialog-actions>
    
  <button
    mat-stroked-button
    (click)="reset()"
    >
    Clear
  </button>
  <button
    mat-dialog-close
    mat-stroked-button>
    Cancle
  </button>
  <button
    (click)="save()"
    mat-raised-button>
    Save
  </button>

  <p>Form data: {{ form.value | json }}</p>

</mat-dialog-actions>
```

any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Your upload method should have no business in dealing with that array. It returns (a promise for) the download url and (an observable of) the upload percentage, and that's all it is responsible for. The *caller* of this method, the one that might call it multiple times concurrently, should deal with putting this in the array. Now where exactly is the problem? Please show us the code of your method and the attempt to use it in that component.

Comment: I'm pretty sure he was referring to the *caller* - why is everyone so literal and ready to degrade people?

Comment: yes i didnt mean i wanted to do this array set up inside the ```upload(file)``` method, but theoretically speaking, how do you go about returning a promise and an observable from the same function/method?

Comment: @DIGIByte I'm pretty sure he wasn't - the question asks how to return this from the upload method itself.

Comment: @breadman0 Just return both as part of an object - quite like the object that you'd then push into that array. Can you please [edit] your question to include the code of your working `upload` method, so that we can help you more specifically?

Comment: @breadman0 are you using plain typescript or a framework like Angular?

Comment: @DIGIByte, @Bergi I will update with source code. I am using Angular. I see where @Bergi confusion arises- the component which contains the ```upload``` method is also of a similar name - ```upload-image```,so that may have been miscontrued in my wording. I am trying to pass this download and percent betweeen image-upload and the parent component, so that i can display a progress bar and save the downloadURL in firestore when the (parent) form submits

Comment: the current source code doesnt show that data exchange between child and parent, because im first concerned with reliably getting this data in the upload method. Once I figure that out i will do something like ```uploadCompletedEvent({downloadURL, uploadPercent})``` from within upload method and then listen for that event in EditNewsComponent

Comment: I didn't want to make assumptions on the framework, typescript is too vague when you are also dependant on angular methods. I don't believe there was any confusion, I didn't see a need to take your literal words as the problem only that you had an issue that you wanted to resolve
Since we've clarified that it is Angular, you can look at how Fireship has it working with Angular/fire
https://fireship.io/lessons/angular-firebase-storage-uploads-multi/

Comment: @DIGIByte Very nice thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is certainly possible, you will need to adjust to the design of your project

Fireship.io has a really nice solution with Angular/Fire
Source: https://fireship.io/lessons/angular-firebase-storage-uploads-multi/

*upload-task.component.ts*

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Input, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireStorage, AngularFireUploadTask } from '@angular/fire/storage';
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { finalize, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'upload-task',
  templateUrl: './upload-task.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./upload-task.component.scss']
})
export class UploadTaskComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() file: File;

  task: AngularFireUploadTask;

  percentage: Observable<number>;
  snapshot: Observable<any>;
  downloadURL: string;

  constructor(private storage: AngularFireStorage, private db: AngularFirestore) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.startUpload();
  }

  startUpload() {

    // The storage path
    const path = `test/${Date.now()}_${this.file.name}`;

    // Reference to storage bucket
    const ref = this.storage.ref(path);

    // The main task
    this.task = this.storage.upload(path, this.file);

    // Progress monitoring
    this.percentage = this.task.percentageChanges();

    this.snapshot   = this.task.snapshotChanges().pipe(
      tap(console.log),
      // The file's download URL
      finalize( async() =>  {
        this.downloadURL = await ref.getDownloadURL().toPromise();

        this.db.collection('files').add( { downloadURL: this.downloadURL, path });
      }),
    );
  }

  isActive(snapshot) {
    return snapshot.state === 'running' && snapshot.bytesTransferred < snapshot.totalBytes;
  }

}
```